# How do I make a portable executable application on Golang with the GTK3 GUI?

Tags: go, gtk3

I wrote a small Windows application on Golang with a GUI on gotk3 (bindings for GTK 3). How do I make an executable file portable? That is, how do I compile the code so that it can be run on a computer without installing dlls like libcairo, libfontconfig, libgdk, etc.

Comment: I've never used this, but have you looked at: https://wails.app/ ?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I think Wails is not a good choice for me for some reasons. Although maybe I'll try it sometime. I am currently interested in GTK, for this I have a glade file with the interface I'm needed. If this is interesting, there is a list of Go GUI/graphics/image related projects https://github.com/go-graphics/go-gui-projects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same application, and what I do is to copy these dll files and share into a bundle. You can have a look at https://github.com/sunshine69/gnote specially this https://github.com/sunshine69/gnote/blob/4821be5e9c930994a8699b27c20ccbbe00917586/forms/utils.go#L353 as a start.

Best luck